# retrieve dir structure in gerrit for a project using REST API

Tags: git, rest, gerrit

Is there any way to retrieve folder and files in a particular branch in gerrit using rest api.Can we retrive the entire dir structure of a particular project.

According to gerrit documentation https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html 
this query "/projects/{project-name}/branches/{branch-id}/files" should retrieve all the files and folders in a particular branch but it is throwing site can’t be reached error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#get-content), I wasn't able to find any mention to "/projects/{project-name}/branches/{branch-id}/files" endpoint, I only found:

> 'GET /projects/{project-name}/branches/{branch-id}/files/{file-id}/content'
>
> Gets the content of a file from the HEAD revision of a certain branch.

Which works as explained.

I think it's not possible to get the contents of a directory by REST.

Comment: Thanks for the response I found this documentation where u can get files for a particular commit https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-files .Is there any way i can fetch all the commit files in master branch so i can get all the files

Comment: No, the {commit-id} works the same way, you can just retrieve a specific file using {commit-id}/files/{file-id}/content.

Comment: Trying to find an API for listing files in a branch, but there doesn't appear to be done. Even the API call that searches files for the autocomplete list when adding a file to a change in the UI seems to hit a change-specific API. Seems nonsensical to implement that API that way.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try below if you using gitiles plugin

`GET /plugins/gitiles/{project-name}/+/{branch-id}/?format=json`

Comment: not a complete solution though, needs to come up with a recursion